# Does SAM4S have FPU onboard?

Tags: arm, datasheet

While trying to use Atmel's [ASF library](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrsoftwareframework.aspx?tab=overview), they say

> - **__FPU_PRESENT:**
>     Initialize macro __FPU_PRESENT = 1 when building on FPU supported Targets. Enable this macro for M4bf and M4lf libraries

So I guess I need to check the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel_11100_32-bit-Cortex-M4-Microcontroller_SAM4S_Datasheet.pdf) if my uC, ATSAM4S16C AU has a floating-point unit and if so, define the macro before including the header inside my project.

But I can't figure the datasheet. Section 12.4.6 lists entries like

> VADD.F32    |   {Sd,} Sn, Sm |  Floating-point Add

However, no clock cycles indicated. Searching the document for FPU or F32 yields nothing. Checking the instruction, only ADD is documented, no VADD.32. So I do not know if this is computed in hardware or in software (in libm.a).

How do I know if the SAM4 has an FPU?

Comment: Not really sure on this but I think all Cortex-M4 cores have it. But you could probably just try enabling and see if some code involving a fair bit of floating point math actually works.

Comment: No, they don't. It's optional in the M4: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABGHFIB.html

Comment: @TomL. Thanks I didn't realise that and your answer looks correct.

Comment: Unfortunately the Atmel site doesn't specify FPU as a searchable parameter (which would be nice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this graphic](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/sam_cortex/) no FPU is available on the SAM4 **S** family. Yet, the SAM4 **X** family should have it.

Comment: So let's see how much is going to speed up my floating point calculations using ASF's arm_math.a instead of the standard libm.a, on a CPU without FPU.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [device webpage](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAM4S16C) from microchip, there is an FPU available.

Also, the __FPU_PRESENT macro on SAM**4S**D32C is set. To answer your original question, you can check with this snippet:

```
#ifndef __FPU_PRESENT
#warning "no FPU!"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_ARM-based_processors#SAM_4) is a list of Atmel SAM4 MCUs, some of which have an FPU.  You want a Cortex-M4F architecture, not a Cortex-M4.  The SAM4S does not have an FPU.